# How to set up HTTPS using Lets Encrypt, Node, and Express 4

Tags: https, node.js, ubuntu-16.04, lets-encrypt

## What I've Done

I used `certbot` to certify that I own my domain, which generated several `.pem` files. The certificates are listed here: https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#where-are-my-certificates

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11744975/enabling-https-on-express-js/11745114#11745114) which makes sense and matches all of the other information I'm getting from Googling around, but when I do this and run node I can't connect to my site using https. Http works fine as it always has.

My server is express.js + node.js and I'm not using a reverse proxy like nginx. It's running on Ubuntu on Google Cloud Platform.

The relevant code is:

```
var http = require('http');
var https = require('https');
var privateKey  = fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/troywolters.com/privkey.pem', 'utf8');
var certificate = fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/troywolters.com/fullchain.pem', 'utf8');
var credentials = {key: privateKey, cert: certificate};
var app = express();

// Lots of other express stuff (app.use()'s)

var httpServer = http.createServer(app);
var httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);
httpServer.listen(80);
httpsServer.listen(443);
```

## What doesn't work

When I try to connect to my site using https://troywolters.com the connection times out and nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does `netstat -lnp` show on your server? How is the firewall configured?

Comment: The relevant lines seem too be `tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      8689/node` and `tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      8689/node`. I've never done anything with a firewall on this server so I'm not sure.

Comment: Please add the complete output to the question, it is easier to read from there.

Comment: as whom does the app run, does that use have read access to `/etc/letsencrypt/live/troywolters.com/privkey.pem`

Comment: looking at https://github.com/ayanray/express4_SSL_example/blob/master/app.js I'm not sure your config is correct

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking#firewalls

Comment: @TeroKilkanen I added the complete output to the question

Comment: @JacobEvans I was hoping that would fix it but changing ownership to my user account (using chown) and giving full permissions (via chmod) didn't fix it :(

Comment: Also, if you'd like to use Let's Encrypt directly with node.js without all the certbot setup, you can use Greenlock: https://git.coolaj86.com/coolaj86/greenlock-express.js

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the problem was that my hosting platform (Google Cloud Platform) did not allow port 443 through the firewall in the default configuration. Running

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules create allow-https --description "Incoming https allowed." --allow tcp:443
```

allowed incoming traffic through port 443 and fixed the problem.

Thank you to Michael Hampton for the tip.